# How to add IBM WAS 8.5 in NetBeans 8.2

Tags: websphere-liberty, websphere-8, netbeans-8.2

Hi I need add WebSphere Application Server Version 8.5.5.3 Liberty Profile to my NetBeans 8.2, but I can't do it from WasCe plugin, that's only for Apache Geronimo and IBM WebSphere AS CE.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

Compile and install this plugin: https://github.com/tjmcmanus/NetbeansLibertyPlugin.git

Use this pom.xml file instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.netbeans.modules.liberty</groupId>
    <artifactId>NetBeansLibertyPlugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>nbm</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useDefaultManifestFile>true</useDefaultManifestFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netbeans</id>
            <name>Repository hosting NetBeans modules</name>
            <url>http://bits.netbeans.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-server</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-nodes</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-dialogs</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-util</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-util-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-awt</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-filesystems</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-io</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-keyring</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-filesystems-nb</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-api-templates</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-util-lookup</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-openide-actions</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-j2eeserver</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-project-libraries</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-java-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-j2eeapis</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--fix transitive dependency by Ricardo Guillen-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-core</artifactId>
            <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
          <artifactId>org-netbeans-api-annotations-common</artifactId>
          <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!--update version by Ricardo Guillen-->
        <netbeans.version>RELEASE82</netbeans.version>
    </properties>
    <name>NetBeansLibertyPlugin</name>
</project>
```

Comment: I was able to compile and install the plugin in netbeans successfully with the POM you provided, but I cannot start the newly created Liberty Server. I get NullPointerException

Comment: I was able to compile and create webshpere server. However the websphere properties shows nothing. so I couldnt start the server